# Operator overloading in Java

Tags: java

Acordding to my knowledge in java I know, that there is no operator overloading in the Java language.
So, why this code prints 'true' twice ?

```
    String s1 = "abc";
    String s2 = "abc";
    System.out.println(s1==s2);

    Integer i1 = 1;
    Integer i2 = 1;
    System.out.println(i1==i2);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`==` for reference types compares the references; `==` for primitive types compares values. In case of your first example, the two object references turn out to be the same due to a concept known as string pool. Hence two `true` in the given case. Another code snippet you might want to try out:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = new String("abc");
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

As you must have already tried out; it prints out `false` and then `true`. The reason for this is that using the `new` keyword results in the creation of a completely new string even though a string object with the exact same contents already exists in the string pool. In this case, `s1` now points to an interned string with the contents "abc" (or to a string in the string pool) whereas `s2` now points to a completely new string object (again with the content "abc"). Hence the `false` in the first print statement.

In the second print statement, what we are doing is comparing the contents of the String object rather than its reference, which as it should prints `true`.

This is one of the most common mistakes made by beginners of the Java language; they use `==` for logical comparison when it actually results in a reference comparison. Read the link posted in one of the answers here for more details about string pooling. On a related note, String class "overrides" the `equals` method of the `Object` class to provide a logical comparison. Unless the class you write doesn't provide a logical implementation of the `equals` method, it doesn't matter whether you call `equals` or use the `==` operator; the result would be the same i.e. reference comparison.

For a more in-depth view on equality, [read Brian's article; an excellent read](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html).

Comment: it prints : false and than true. what the 'new' did here ?

Comment: @Oz, see my updated answer for more details and ask back if you still have questions.

Answer (score 14):

It's not *entirely* true that there is no operator-overloading in Java. There just isn't any **custom** operator overloading. For example there's some operator-overloading with `+` which adds as both addition and as `String`-concatenation. This is defined by the language and can't be modified by the developer.

Your example, however doesn't use operator overloading anywhere. `==` on reference types always does the same thing: return `true` when the left side and the right side refer to the **exact same object**.

In this case `s1` and `s2` reference the same object and `i1` and `i2` reference the same object as well.

- `s1` and `s2` reference the same interned `String`, because string literals are guaranteed to be interned.
- `i1` and `i2` reference the same cached `Integer` because auto-boxing will re-use a fixed pool of `Integer` objects for common numeric values.

Answer (score 5):

*You* don't get to overload operators, but that doesn't mean that it's not built into the JVM itself.  The obvious counter example is the plus operator and the different behavior for String and numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This is because "All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned."

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows like its was related to operator overloading, but, is not.

String "==" operator seems to be "overloded" with Integer "==" operator. As @Sanjay T. Sharma mentioned in a previous answer, in Java there are "reference" types, and "primitive" types, which handles different the "==" operator.

Strings in Java are "reference" types, and integers are "primitive" types. If you have use pointers and objects in other languages, you will find that in Java, a string variables, is really a pointer to an object, and using the "==" operator behaves different.